# Scatter plot with column names on x-axis with classes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a scatter plot where the x-axis is discrete (day of the week) and the y-axis is continuous (values) and a class indicator which gives a color to each data point.

similar to this: [Plotting column names as x-axis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214739/plotting-column-names-as-x-axis-in-r)

but I don't want to use all of the columns in the data and the colors were based on the observation number which I don't want.

example data:

```
DAT = data.frame(
  person = c(1:5),
  Mon = c(100, 98, 95, 99, 93),
  Tues = c(95, 88, 90, 91, 87),
  Wed = c(85, 80, 86, 81, 80),
  Thurs = c(84, 80, 77, 75, 74),
  Fri = c(66, 50, 20, 0, 72),
  Score = c("Y","Y","N","N","N")
)

ggplot(DAT, aes(x = c(Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri), y = values, color = Score)) + geom_point()
```

my attempt/pesuedo ggplot code which does not work but hopefully gives an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I tried to make Mon-Fri as numbers (1,2,3,4,5) so that would be my x coordinates and the values would be the y-coordinates but that would mean 5 times the number of rows..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could melt your data and then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

DAT = data.frame(
  person = c(1:5),
  Mon = c(100, 98, 95, 99, 93),
  Tues = c(95, 88, 90, 91, 87),
  Wed = c(85, 80, 86, 81, 80),
  Thurs = c(84, 80, 77, 75, 74),
  Fri = c(66, 50, 20, 0, 72),
  Score = c("Y","Y","N","N","N")
)

DAT.melt = melt(DAT,id=c("person","Score"))

ggplot(DAT.melt, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = Score)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

First: your data is "wide" (days as columns). Better to make it "long" (a column for days, another column for values).

Then: you need to order the days - make the variable a factor and set the levels.

`tidyr::gather()` to make data long, `dplyr::mutate` to order the days.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

DAT %>% 
  gather(Day, Value, -person, -Score) %>% 
  mutate(Day = factor(Day, levels = c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Day, Value)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = Score))
```

[image]