# Plot several distribution and color it with a gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, melt

I would like to make a distribution plot like in this publication : 
[image: plot]

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-35738-0.pdf

for this I have a table consisting of 24 col each col representing a chromosome and each row a sample
And I have a 25th col consisting in a score i would like to use as a gradient to color the distribution.

I tried to apply the code i found here:
[Plotting column names as x-axis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214739/plotting-column-names-as-x-axis-in-r)

and so I got this plot:

[image]

So here is my code :

```
my_data <- read.table(my_file, header=TRUE, sep=';')
my_data <- my_data[,2:(ncol(my_data))]
rs      <- as.data.frame(t(my_data))
rs$chr <- rownames(rs)
rs      <- melt(rs, id.vars=c("chr"))
ggplot(rs, aes(x=as.factor(chr), y=value)) + geom_point()
```

and here is a piece of my data:

> Sample;1;2;3;4;ff_seqff
>   s1;-1.4368687908545408;-0.35632901567869174;-0.8630635469138286;0.08972089597838186;0.102953198414832
>   s2;1.0899445208946068;-0.7895300680366577;-1.2080358536312499;-1.8869137000565392;0.0318184922525369

if you have any idea of how to this it would be appreciated !

Comment: Have a look at dot plots e.g. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-dot-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Comment: Also `ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom`: https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm